# UIMenucontroller with uitextview on uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview, uimenucontroller

I have a UITextView inside my custom UITableViewCell. I am using UITextView basically for providing data detection on cell. I have my own custom UIMenuitems set for different cells.

```
              |-------------------------------|
              |                               |
              |   |------------------|        |
              |   |                  |        |
              |   |        UITextView|        |
              |   |__________________|        |
              |                               |
              |                UITableViewCell|
              |_______________________________|
```

Issue that I am facing is that when I tap the area within UITextView i don't get any menu controller, the expected behavior is, it should call same menu controller that is define for that particulate UITebleViewCell.

If I replace UITextView with UILabel i get proper menu controller but I loose data detection capability.

Please guide me in proper direction, what am I missing or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the data detection you are meaning?

Comment: I want to detect phone number, link, address, events so i am using [_textView setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeAll];

Answer (score 1):

You can use **UITapGestureRecognizer** to detect a tap on your textview.

- Make sure **userInteractionEnabled** is TRUE for your textView

> myTextView.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

- Add gesture recognizer for your text view

> ```
> UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myTextViewTapped:)];
> [myTextView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
> ```

- Display menu controller on tap

> ```
> - (void)myTextViewTapped:(id)sender {
>     NSLog(@"my text view is tapped");
>     // display menu now!
>
> }
> ```

- If your menu controller depends on individual cell then you can use the row number as tag of your textView and display relevant menu controller

> ```
> // in your tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath method
>
> myTextView.tag = indexPath.row;
>
> // in your selector
>
> UITextView *myTextView = (UITextView *)sender;
> int rowNumber = myTextView.tag;
> ```